# If condition is not equal batch file crashes

Tags: batch-file

I have been writing some batch files now-a-days. I am beginner !. So i have made a custom batch in which by entering a setup name it launches it but. I'am having some problem creating this custom file.

```
    @echo off
set /p lnk="Setup Name = "
if "%lnk%"=="install.itunes.x64.windows" goto itunes
:itunes
start=(path)(setup.exe).....
cls
```

But if a user enters "itues or "installitunes" or "KJEWBFciou" whatever that don't matchs my custom command I want a error Pop-up in this condition. 
What can i Do?
and don't ask to put `"if not "%lnk%"` i have already tried help level:0
Because i have many setups like itunes if input will not equal to custom command it launches the next setup.
Please help me

Please igonre my errors i only made 'em here not in batch file.
in line 2 %lnk%   , lnk
and line 3  "%lnk"   ,"%lnk%"

Comment: Remove the percent symbols from the SET /P command.

Comment: `"%lnk%` should also be `"%lnk%"`

Comment: After the `if` command you fall into `:itunes` section unintentionally, so you'll need a `goto :EOF` or `goto `:somewhere_else` after the `if`...

Answer (score 0):

Ok so..

```
1 @echo off
2  set /p %lnk%="Setup Name = "
3  if "%lnk%=="install.itunes.x64.windows" goto itunes
4  :itunes
5  start=(path)(setup.exe).....
6  cls
```

A few errors but you're close.

In line 2, you use:

```
set /p %lnk%=="Setup Name = " goto itunes
```

When setting a variable you can't use %% around it, but thats only used when comparing, because when creating the variable, the computer will replace [set /p %lnk%=] with [set /p =] which is invalid syntax.

In line 3:

```
if "%lnk%=="install.itunes.x64.windows" goto itunes
```

You never closed the quotes on the left of the '==' comparison. Do note you can also use [if %val1% equ %val2%] to the same results, which can help when you want to use other comparison tags.

A sidenote for the task you have set, although [goto itunes] works fine, its a good habit to use [goto :itunes] instead, and if you want to keep your code all together, you can just make a code block like:

```
  if %val1% equ %val2% (
rem do stuff here
)
```

do note, if you either want a task to run  if variables match, and if not try the next match, you can use multiple of these. Otherwise you can use:

```
 if %val1% equ %val2% (
   rem do stuff here
 ) else (
   rem do other stuff here
)
```

In response to your issue on it launching the next command, thats because in line 3, you check if the variable matches your string, but if it doesnt batch skips it and runs the next line, which is your :itunes label.
All in all, this should work better, after you fix [start=(path)(setup.exe).....] to launch as desired.

```
@echo off && color f0 && title Itunes

:top
cls
set /p lnk="Setup Name = "

 if "%lnk%"=="install.itunes.x64.windows" (
   start=(path)(setup.exe).....
   cls
)
cls 
echo "%lnk%" was not matched to any choices...
pause
goto :top
```

:: _Arescet